# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException cuando borro el único registro de mi tabla y al iniciar el programa en Java

Tags: java, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi tabla de mi base de datos, solo tengo 1 registro.

1. Cuando arranco el programa el error se presenta.
2. Hago clic en OK para obviarlo y el programa abre, si trato de
   eliminar ese registro, también recibo el mismo error.
3. Por alguna razón, los registros no se guardan empezando con el ID #1
   en la base de datos.

Código del método table.Registros(String buscar) de mi clase Ventana_Usuario:

```
void tableRegistros(String buscar) {
        Logica_usuario logica_usuario = new Logica_usuario();
        try {
            logica_usuario = new Logica_usuario();
            DefaultTableModel model;
            model = logica_usuario.tableRegistros(buscar);
            table.setModel(model);
            table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            setColumnsWidth(); 
            mostrarInformes();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception:\n" + e, "Error: Ventana_Usuario.tableRegistros(String buscar)", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
    }
```

Código del método tableRegistros(String buscar) en mi clase Logica_usuario:

```
public DefaultTableModel tableRegistros(String buscar) {
        DefaultTableModel model = null;

        sSQL = "SELECT usuario.*, perfil.nombre AS nombrePerfil FROM perfil INNER JOIN usuario ON perfil.id_perfil = usuario.id_perfil WHERE usuario.nombre LIKE '%" + buscar + "%' ORDER BY id_usuario";

        // Java 7 try-with-resources
        try (Statement st = con.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL)) {

            String [] titulosColumnas = {"ID", "Nombre", "Apellido", "Usuario", "Contraseña", "Perfil"};
            rs.last();
            int filas = rs.getRow();
            rs.first();
            Object [][] registros = new Object[filas][titulosColumnas.length]; 

            int i = 0;
            do {


                registros[i][0] = rs.getInt("id_usuario");
                registros[i][1] = rs.getString("nombre");
                registros[i][2] = rs.getString("apellido");
                registros[i][3] = rs.getString("usuario");
                registros[i][4] = rs.getString("contrasena");
                registros[i][5] = rs.getString("nombrePerfil");

                i++;
            } while (rs.next());

            model = new DefaultTableModel(registros, titulosColumnas);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e, "Error: Logica_usuario.tableRegistros(String buscar)", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        return model;
    }
```

Alguna idea de el por qué el Exception cuando la tabla de mi base de datos esta vacía y cuando intento borrar un registro?.

Nota: Si agrego manualmente varios registos desde la base de datos, el programa arranca sin problemas y puedo borrar registros desde el programa sin problemas.

Espero puedan ayudarme, estoy perdido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Alguna idea de el por qué el Exception cuando la tabla de mi base de datos esta vacía y cuando intento borrar un registro?"
El error esta en el do-while porque cuando no tienes registros no puedes hacer esto...

```
     registros[i][0] = rs.getInt("id_usuario");...
```

ya que la consulta no arroja resultados.

Puedes cambiarlo a solo un while o antes verificar si hubo resultados en la consulta.

Editado...
como te digo hay dos formas... la primera el que pongas una condicion antes de ejecutar el do-while.

```
        if(rs.hasRow()){ 
            //ejecutas do-while 
        }  
        else { 
           //llenas una colunma vacia de registros 
           //si quieres que se muestre un reglon vacio.
            registros[0][0] = "";
            registros[0][1] = "";...
        }
```

La segunda forma sería...

```
       while(rs.next()){
             registros[i][0] = rs.getInt("id_usuario");
             registros[i][1] = rs.getInt...//todo lo que tiene en el do
       }
```

Comment: Alberto podrías ponerle la corrección de tu propuesta, es la respuesta correcta.

Comment: como te digo hay dos formas... la primera el que pongas una condicion antes de ejecutar el do-while. if(rs.hasRow()){ //ejecutas do-while } else { //llenas una colunma vacia de registros si quieres que se muestre un reglon vacio}

Comment: la otra forma es... while (rs.next()){  registros[i][0] = rs.getInt("id_usuario");
                registros[i][1] = rs.getString("nombre");
                registros[i][2] = rs.getString("apellido");
                registros[i][3] = rs.getString("usuario");
                registros[i][4] = rs.getString("contrasena");
                registros[i][5] = rs.getString("nombrePerfil");

                i++; }  //Espero te funcione, si no me dices ppara ver que onda porque yo lo trabajo con C# pero es similar a java

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para que se vea mejor estilizada tu respuesta.